# Should questions or answers centered on the Velominati Rules be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've found a number of answers which are essentially "Obey rule 25", "Obey rule 10", etc.  These rules link to the [Velominati "The Rules" page](http://www.velominati.com/blog/the-rules).

The rules consist of a lengthy list of tongue-in-cheek lines which are mostly superficial in nature and of very little value or substance.  Of the 85 rules, fewer than a handful have any value other than humor.

Should answers which simply cite a given rule be downvoted, and citations of these rules generally discouraged?  I see them as humorous, but without value for a site intended to give values of substance to legitimate questions.  I'd personally prefer these types of answers be included as comments; they could be mentioned in substantial answers--but answers citing these alone should be discouraged.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like these answers should be converted to comments, but can you link to examples?

Comment: The most recent example (although the question itself is quite poor) is: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/bicycle-socks-for-road-rides

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers such as the one you link are not answers, they're comments. Please flag these for moderator attention when you encounter them; we'll convert them into comments as appropriate.

(Also: New users can't comment on questions - as an anti-spam measure, you need 50 rep before you can do that - so a lot of comments by these users end up being written as answers.)

Comment: I agree.  If an "answer" doesn't actually answer the question, it should be flagged as "not an answer". Leaving a comment for the user is a good idea, too. That includes humorous answers and answers that are only a link elsewhere.